# wxpython filebrowsedialog button in Control Desk from dSPACE

Tags: python, wxpython

iam working on a project and need to add a filebrowserdialog to my programm in control desk from dSPACE...

there is a way to do this in wxpython, but the problem is:
i dont know how to implement this in my control desk program..
i need to be able to add a button, when i click on it, it should show a filebrowserdialog and the selected file should appear in a textbox ..

anyone knows how to make it ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create a FileDialog like so:

```
        import os

        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Choose a file",
            defaultDir=os.getcwd(),
            defaultFile="",
            style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR
            )

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            #Set your textCtrl with the value of path here!

        dlg.Destroy()
```

Obviously you'll need to create a button and bind it to a handler which calls the above code.

Then you can set a `wx.TextCtrl` with the path you get when you call `GetPath()` on your FileDialog.

**wx.FileDialog Documentation:**

http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FileDialog-class.html

http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.FileDialog.html

---

***Edit:***
I just noticed the mention of DSPACE, I don't know anything about that, but the above method is how its done in regular *wxPython*.